# C++ Can I cast a pointer from one type to another, then use it as the latter? And is there overhead?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a pointer to a struct.

Can I recast this to `*char` and, assuming I know the size of it including padding, then pass that to some function that could use it as `*char` (for example write it to a file)?

And is doing that free in terms of overhead?

(No need to tell me this is a bad idea, my question is if it is possible and if it is overhead-free.)

Comment: This is one way to do a binary serialization. It may work if  your struct does contain trivial types only. For a pointer (pointing to another instance) or a class which doesn't contain trivial types as well it's a bad idea. I'm not aware of what overhead you're concerned. Please, note that the cast of any pointer to `char*` was explicitly allowed for this purpose.

Comment: You looking for `reinterpret_cast`? Overhead: None, its compile time

Comment: serialization as such is problematic for other concern such as endianess.

Comment: Is the struct trivial or non-trivial?  (in the sense of what is tested by `std::is_trivial<your_struct_type>::value` since C++11 being `true` or `false`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally legal in C++ and free in terms of runtime costs to use `reinterpret_cast<char*>(pointer_to_my_value)`. In place of `char` you can also place `unsigned char` or `std::byte`. As long as you are going only to read this cast data and/or cast it back to original type it is within the bounds of defined behaviour. For more you may want to go [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)

Comment: Cool! Could I cast let's say an `[8]char` to an unsigned 64-bit integer and then compare this with `==` to another `[8]char` cast to an unsigned 64-bit integer? And that would be more efficient than comparing each byte, right?

Comment: As I mentioned, only casting TO `char*` is safe. Casting `char*` to anything is not so simple